# Deploying GWT application / LibGDX and TextureAtlas problem

Tags: libgdx, texture-atlas

I encountered with a little problem. After GWT (and LibGDX) deployment I got an error:

> GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't load image '/images/objects.png',
>   file does not exist Couldn't load image '/images/objects.png', file
>   does not exist

This error throws when TextureAtlas tries to load the image from *settings.text* file:

> images/objects.png
>   format: RGBA8888
>   filter: Nearest,Nearest
>   repeat: none
>   hills
>   rotate: false
>   xy: 0, 0
>   size: 1024, 146
>   orig: 1024, 146
>   offset: 0, 0
>   index: -1

I tried to use any type of path

- "**/assets/images/object.png**"
- "**/clutchkick/assets/images/object.png**"
- "**/public_html/clutchkick/assets/images/object.png**"
- and so on..

Any suggestions?

By the way there are no any problems on android or desktop deployment.

EDIT:
The same problem occurs when trying to load a Tmx map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bug in **com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtFileHandle** that adds a slash before the image path in the atlas, but here is a workaround:

Put the *atlas* files are inside a folder like **"assets/images/"**, don't put it directly in the assets folder, and make sure the *image path* in *atlas* file is correct (relative to atlas), then it should work.

---

Or you can just fix the **GwtFileHandle** class:

Find this code in **com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtFileHandle**

```
public FileHandle child (String name) {
    return new GwtFileHandle(preloader, file + (file.endsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + name, FileType.Internal);
}
```

And change it to following code

```
public FileHandle child (String name) {
    return new GwtFileHandle(preloader, file.isEmpty() ? "" : (file + (file.endsWith("/") ? "" : "/")) + name, FileType.Internal);
}
```

Comment: this bug is still present in 2017, I wasted 2 hours because of it. Thank you!